# What are C# chaining functional approach caveats? What to do with "ifs"?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Recently I watched Pluralsight course "Functional programming in C#". And rewrote some methods in my hobby project. Now they look like this:

```
public override CommandLineResult GetResult()
{
    return Disposable.Using(new IndicatorRepository(), repo =>
    {
        return repo.AddOrUpdateIndicator(Indicator, Value, DateTimeExtensions.LocalNow().Date);
    })
    .Map((p) => new NumericIndicatorRecorderedModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        DbActionPreformed = true,
        IsRewritten = Convert.ToBoolean(p),
        IndicatorName = Indicator,
        Value = Value,
        ValueDate = ValueDate
    })
    .Map((model) => new CommandLineResult()
    {
        ActionName = "~/Views/CommandLine/_clresult_NumericIndicatorRecorderedModel.cshtml",
        Model = model
    });
}
```

There's something pretty about this chaining approach (I removed Using with Disposable class, at every step I have expressions, not statements, etc.).

**But the questions are:**

- Does not this approach covers some dangers? and what are they? (isn't it more difficult to debug for example)
- What usually people do in terms of chaining approach, if it is required to branch the flow of code execution? Break chain with ifs somewhere? Write "map-if" functional extensions (would not that approach create spaghetti code?)?

**UPDATE: more specific question regarding this issue**

What approach to implement code branching is better - to break chaining like this:

```
        public string GetResult(bool param) {
        if (param) {
            return MyClass.DoOneWay(p =>...).AlsoDo(q =>...).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return MyClass.DoOtherWay(p =>...).AlsoDo(q =>...).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Or to implement functional if-helpers, like this:

```
        public string GetResult(bool param)
    {
        return MyClass.DoIf(param, p => ...., q => ....).AlsoDo(q =>...).ToString();
    }
```

And what to do, if there're much more options then just true/false? 
How to "functionaly" implement "switch" branching?

Comment: This is a very broad question. As regarding to the dangers, that really depends how you handle exceptions, for example. Some languages have the notion of an `Option<T>` which can either return something, or nothing. Also, there can be a `Validation<T>` which either returns an error msg or the actual value, it really depends on you. Regarding the branching, you can take an example from `Expression` in C#, where you have a `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` where you provide an expression for greater than and an expression for equal.